# Mapping with different datatypes showing on one struct

Tags: contract-development, addresses, mapping, struct, data-types

is it possible that in I can use a uint and a address that showing on the same struct(Submission) as mapping ? I need something what makes it easy to read out the mapping with a uint (number) and with a address. What could be the best way to do that ? Thank you in advance !

```
 struct Submission {
    uint id;
    Student student;
    Examiner examiner;
    Thesis thesis;
    // examniner accepts allocation
    bool accepted;
    // examiner finished correction
    bool corrected;
    // examiner marks submission as verified
    bool verified;
}

 // save submission in mapping with id as key
mapping(uint => Submission) public submissions;
```

Comment: Do you want that both uint and address map to the same struct in the same mapping?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! And that I can read out the mapping either with the address or with the uint. But without needing both(the address and the uint)